# Solr 4.0 XML Query Delete all

Tags: xml, solr

What is the solr XML Query to delete all of the data in a core I have tried,
`curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>id:*</query></delete>'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try :-

With Curl -

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

Be sure to use commit=true to reflect these changes.

OR from Browse -

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option in cmd with java:
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update -Ddata=args -Dcommit=yes -jar post.jar "*:*"
All of this in post directory.